# Why is my login error message not displaying in Python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have created a login page with Python flask , that is connected to an SQLite3 database. When I enter the correct user details , I login into the system as expected. But when I enter incorrect details , the login page just refreshes without showing the error message.

Here is my code

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

r = ""
msg = ""
if (request.method == "POST"):
    usertype = request.form["UserType"]
    username = request.form["Username"]
    password = request.form["Password"]
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT UserType,Username,Password FROM users WHERE UserType='" + usertype + "' and Username= '" + username + "' and Password='" + password + "'")
    r = c.fetchall()
    for i in r:
        if (usertype == i[0] and username == i[1] and password == i[2]):
            session["loginsuccess"] = True
            session["username"] = username
            return redirect(url_for("navigate"))
        else:
            msg = "Please enter correct login details"



return render_template("Login.html", msg=msg)
```

Html code

```
`<label>Username</label><br>
<input name="Username" type=Username placeholder="Enter username" required
 oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Username is required')"
 oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"/><br><br>
<label>Password</label><br>
<input name="Password" type=Password placeholder="Enter password" required
 oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Password is required')"
 oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"><br><br>

<p>{{msg}}</p>
```

Comment: Add a line `print('Display message: %s' % msg)`
before your `return render_template....`
to be sure that `msg` have the right value.

Comment: Your message is only displayed if **at least one** record is returned from the query. Of course if you enter an invalid username, no record is returned from the query. So your code in the for loop is never executed and the message never updated.

Answer (score 0):

In your code base if query return at least one result then only your msg will be displayed else it won't. So try this code.

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    msg = ""
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        usertype = request.form["UserType"]
        username = request.form["Username"]
        password = request.form["Password"]
        conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT UserType,Username,Password FROM users "
                    "WHERE UserType='" + usertype + "' and Username= '" + username + "' and Password='" + password + "'")
        result = cur.fetchall()
        if result:
            for i in result:
                if usertype == i[0] and username == i[1] and password == i[2]:
                    session["loginsuccess"] = True
                    session["username"] = username
                    return redirect(url_for("navigate"))
        else:
            msg = "Please enter correct login details"
    return render_template("Login.html", msg=msg)
```